# Accounting for dynamic response assertions in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have been assigned for automated testing of Web services to achieve the following in soapUI:

Basically before the soap message is send everytime it should be replaced with another test data. For example, if I have 10 test cases, then the next test case overwrites the previous one. Test Case 10 is what I finally see on the screen. The advantage is that you only need one soap request message and through a loop the soap message is refilled with the new test data(data driven) and sent.

The problem I consider now is that for each response message applies different assertions. It’s not possible to have global assertions for all response messages because every response message looks different and therefore it is necessary to have specific assertions for each response message. The problem is that I can’t hold the assertions for the specific response message because it’s then rewritten by the next response message. The response message by testcase 10 is what I finally see on the screen. You got the problem

A possible solution:

- Save each response message separately.
- Get each response message separately and enter the corresponding assertions for that specific respons.

Does anyone have an elegant solution or experience with the above and got it working well ?

Comment: Please provide a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using a data source and data loop.

In the data source, have your input values AND your assertion.

Then, you just make the response assertion a variable pointing to the data source.  Structure would then look like this:

```
- Test Steps
--  Data Source
--  SOAP Request
---- Assertion
--  Data Loop
```

Comment: BlackGaff, Thnx a lot for the explanation and solution you described. I will implement this in my testscript ;)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please consider marking this as as "answered" if it works for you.